# Replacing CR2032 batteries with AAs to power bathroom scales

Tags: batteries

My digital bathroom scales take 2 CR2032 batteries that I seem to have to replace all the time.

Can I simply replace them with 4 AA (or AAA) batteries (assuming I can find room) or do I need to regulate the current to avoid blowing up the circuit?

Comment: As long as the voltage is about the same (5.5 to 6.5V) then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can. If you fit the Voltage the thing should work.